# Passing fields to the post_save hook for user profiles?

Tags: python, django

I have a user profile I've created that needs to have some parameters passed to it to avoid `IntegrityError`'s, such as non-nullable fields. I wrote my creation hook as described [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222) on the bottom of the page, but when I call `create_user`, I get integrity errors since the `create_user` is trying to save the user I just created with the uninitialized profile. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no detail at the provided link on how to automatically create a user profile, so I'm not sure how you've actually set that up. However, this is the typical way:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

signals.post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

It sounds like your problem is that `UserProfile` (or your equivalent model) has additional fields that cannot be null, and as such, you want to provide values for those fields. However, that's simply not possible using a `post_save` signal. Generally all non-char fields on a profile are nullable or provide sensible defaults, so then, you can at least create the object without specific info. Through your interface, you can enforce that users fill out their profiles, but it's not prudent to enforce that at the database level.